# Problems with Google Analytics Event Tracking

Tags: javascript, html, google-analytics

This question has been asked many times over on SO. I am sorry to be asking once more.

I've read, re-read, and re-re-read the GA documentation and still cannot get my GA Event Tracking to display.

I have a series of links which lead away from a website and am attempting to track how much action they get.

Here is my ga.js:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var _gaq = _gaq || [];
    _gaq.push(['_setAccount', 'UA-123456-1']);
    _gaq.push(['_setDomainName', 'somewebsite.com']);
    _gaq.push(['_trackPageview']);

    (function() {
      var ga = document.createElement('script'); ga.type = 'text/javascript'; ga.async = true;
      ga.src = ('https:' == document.location.protocol ? 'https://ssl' : 'http://www') + '.google-analytics.com/ga.js';
      var s = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0]; s.parentNode.insertBefore(ga, s);
    })();
  </script>
```

Here are a few of links. Both links are built on top Font Awesome icons. Not sure if that matters.

```
<li><a href="https://somewebsite1.com" onClick="_gaq.push(['_trackEvent', 'Links', 'Click1', 'somewebsite1"]);"><i id="git" class="fa fa-github-alt fa-2x"></i></a></li>

<li><a href="http://somewebsite2.com" onClick="_gaq.push(['_trackEvent', 'Links', 'Click2', 'somewebsite2']);"><i id="linked" class="fa fa-linkedin-square fa-2x"></i></a></li>
```

Thank you very much.

Comment: Google's documentation has a good explanation on how to do this: https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/1136920?hl=en

Comment: do you have other code attached to the link that's perhaps stopping the onclick code from triggering?  add a simple `alert('hi')` before the `_gaq` calls in the onclick. Do they trigger? In any case, I have a feeling what is *probably* happening is you are being redirected before the GA code has a chance to finish triggering. You need to follow the example in the link provided by @StevenV

Comment: 1. In the first event line your quotes are off. 'somewebsite1"]); should be 'somewebsite1']); 2. You could try adding the fourth parameter to the call. It's an integer that I generally leave at 1.